# How is this space complexity calculated in this series sum?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, space-complexity

Can someone explain the following space complexity calculation to me?

> Given a stream of numbers of size b bits, calculate the sum of these
>   numbers.
>
> If we have seen T numbers so far, the sum is at most T2^b and hence
>   needs at most O(b+log T) space.

Now, T2^b must be an upper bound because a more accurate upper bound would be T(2^b - 1).

But how did they calculate that the space upper bound is O(b +logT)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With *m* bits, you can store numbers up to (about) *2<sup>m</sup>*. So, working the other way, if you know the sum, you need to take a logarithm to get the number of bits (and hence the space complexity).

Here, *log(T 2<sup>b</sup>) = b + log(T)*.